# Verify if something exists in DB using API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a class that checks if the email exists in the database, and I'm creating on repository where I have all method from API, I'm not sure is a good idea, but I don't know what to do.

**Interface Repository**:

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    ...
    void Verify (User user);
}
```

**Repository:**

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly ConnectDB context;

    public UserRepository(ConnectDB ctx)
    {
        context = ctx;
    }

    public void Verify(User user)
    {
        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand check_User_Name = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Users] WHERE ([Email] = @user)" , connect);
        check_User_Name.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user.Email);
        int UserExist = (int)check_User_Name.ExecuteScalar();

        if(UserExist > 0)
        {
        //Username exist
        //context.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
        //Username doesn't exist.
        //context.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
}
```

Controller to create and where I want verify, I think this is the way to do it:

```
[HttpPost("create")]
    public IActionResult Create(User user)
    {
        if (?????)
        {
            return mensage with error
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                if(user == null)
                    return BadRequest();
                User newUser = user;
                userRepository.Add(newUser);

                return Ok(newUser);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return  StatusCode(500,ex.InnerException.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

My big questions are, first is the idea right? What I put on `if`?

```
if(UserExist > 0)
{
   //Username exist
}
else
{
   //Username doesn't exist.
}
```

And how I can receive on the controller the answer?

I try put on `if`, if exist `true` and if doesn't exist `false`, but doesn't work because method is `void` and not `bool`.

Comment: Why not make `Verify` return a bool, then?

Comment: i tried once, didin't work i go try again

Comment: i think worked, but now the problem is other so i think thanks ;)

Comment: is this resolved?

Comment: i think so, now the problem is `ExecuteScalar requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.`, is different from the question.

Comment: Now show error in this line `int UserExist = (int)check_User_Name.ExecuteScalar();`

Comment: Try opening your connection?

Comment: @stuartd i have this for open connection at least i think, `SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection();`, `connect.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-I8E3ENQ;Initial Catalog=teste;Integrated Security=True"`

Comment: `connect.Open()`

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can check if the user exists before creating, it makes sense.

You may want to create a bool method in your repository like below

```
public bool CheckIfUserExist(User user)
{
    // check if the user exists in your DB
}
```

In your **Create** API, you can call the above repository method through the service layer, if the method returns *false*, you should proceed to create the user otherwise throw a validation error saying the user already exists.